# Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to run this code that will get the first 7 columns from sheet1 in spreadsheet1 and paste them in sheet2 in spreadsheet2, but im keep getting this error which I dont know why.

Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. *6th line*

```
function MoveCode(){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zU__ccPIMst54whmyrbmRnDRRjOtQBFPzXhw6NsFqpU");//or url whatever
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const dsh = ss2.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
  const vs = ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow() - 1,7).getValues();
  dsh.getRange(2,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

test3 is the spreadsheet that i want to paste the data to
from.

If you need anymore explanation please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in your script when `ssh.getLastRow()` is less than 2, such an error occurs. Because `ssh.getLastRow() - 1` is 0 and -1. For example, I think that when the sheet "Sheet1" has only the header row and no values, such an error occurs. In order to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function MoveCode(){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###");//or url whatever
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const dsh = ss2.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
  const lastRow = ssh.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow < 2) return;
  const vs = ssh.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 7).getValues();
  dsh.getRange(2, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

- By this modification, when the sheet "Sheet1" has only the header row and no values, the script is finished.

### Added:

From your replying and adding the sample images, when I saw your images, I thought that in your script, `ssh` and `dsh` are used as the source sheet and destination sheet, respectively. But in your sample image, I thought that you might want to use `ssh` and `dsh` as the destination sheet and the source sheet, respectively. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Modified script:

In this case, please be careful about `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` and `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")` for each sheet.

```js
function MoveCode(){
  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###");//or url whatever
  const ssh = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const dsh = ss2.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
  const lastRow = dsh.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow < 2) return;
  const vs = dsh.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 7).getValues();
  ssh.getRange(2, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: @Omar Thank you for replying. When I saw your images, I thought that in your script, `ssh` and `dsh` are used as the source sheet and destination sheet, respectively. But in your sample image, I thought that you might want to use `ssh` and `dsh` as the destination sheet and the source sheet, respectively. For this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your current situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Omar In your current situation, I supposes that `Sheet1` is in `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` and `Sourcing` is in `SpreadsheetApp.openById("###")`. Please confirm this again? If it's the opposit way, please modify it.